# Sending data from website to android app

Tags: php, android

I am developing a location based android app and I want that the app should send me the location data on my server whenever I request using a button on my web page. So how can I send a signal from my website to the android app so that it starts functioning only when I send a request ?
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Google Cloud Messaging Service](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) would be a good starting point.

Answer (score 3):

Basically you need a [Push Notification](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CDgQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.androidhive.info%2F2012%2F10%2Fandroid-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql%2F&ei=xSlIUenBEszprQfmx4DwBg&usg=AFQjCNFwsOBVunF1KdDkDjt1rVUfI4iN5w&bvm=bv.43828540,d.bmk&cad=rja) in your project. The push Notification will allow you to send a signal from website which will catch at mobile side and perform operation accordingly.